# What is the walletname.unportable file?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, keys-file

I have 4 wallet files: 
walletname.address.txt file
walletname.keys file
walletname

What is this type of file?

> walletname.unportable

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file is a copy of the cache file (walletname) as it was when the cache file format changed to use a more portable data storing library. It was kept as a safeguard in case the new format proved buggy, so it can now be discarded.

For reference, the old format was boost serialization, and the new format is portable boost serialization, which is not yet merged in boost to my knowledge.